# Exercise from Norris' book on Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, probability-limit-theorems

Let $(X_n)$ be a Markov chain on $\mathbb{N}$ with transition probabilities satisfying:

$$p_{0,1}=1,\quad p_{i,i-1}+p_{i,i+1}=1,\quad p_{i,i+1}=\left(\frac{i+1}{i}\right)^{\alpha}p_{i,i-1}$$

The exercise asks to find $\mathbb{P}(X_n\to \infty\;\text{as}\;n\to\infty)$

The problem is that I am having real trouble getting started off, because I cannot express the event $X_n\to\infty$ in a more suitable form. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. My first thought was:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_n\to\infty)=\prod_k\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq k\;\text{eventually})=\prod_k \mathbb{P}(X_n \neq 0,\cdots X_n\neq k-1\;\text{eventually})$$

But I am having trouble with translating "eventually".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often, it is difficult to answer this question because the OP says nothing about their background. Anyway, a standard approach to determine the recurrence/transience of a Markov chain (its *type*) is to compute $P_1(T_0\,\text{infinite})$ as the limit of $P_1(T_n\lt T_0)$ when $n\to\infty$, since each $P_1(T_n\lt T_0)$ involves only a finite Markov chain.

In the case at hand, for each positive $n$, the Markov property after one step shows that the quantities $u_i=P_i(T_n\lt T_0)$ solve the system $u_0=0$, $u_n=1$, and, for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1$, $$u_i=p_{i,i+1}u_{i+1}+p_{i,i-1}u_{i-1},$$ Assume furthermore that, as in the case at hand, there exists some positive sequence $(w_i)_{i\geqslant1}$ such that, for every $i\geqslant1$, $$w_{i+1}p_{i,i+1}=w_ip_{i,i-1},$$ then $$\frac{u_{i+1}-u_i}{w_{i+1}}=\frac{u_i-u_{i-1}}{w_i},$$ that is, $$u_{i+1}=u_i+\frac{w_{i+1}}{w_1}u_1,$$ hence, $$u_i=\frac{u_1}{w_1}\sum_{k=1}^iw_k.$$ The limit condition $u_n=1$ shows finally that $$u_1=\frac{w_1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^nw_k}.$$ Thus, when $n\to\infty$, $$P_1(T_n\lt T_0)=\frac{w_1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^nw_k}\to\frac{w_1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty w_k}=P_1(T_0\,\text{infinite}).$$
In the exercise, $w_i=i^{-a}$ hence all this yields:

> - If the series $\sum\limits_kw_k$ diverges, then $P_1(T_0\,\text{infinite})=0$, that is, the Markov chain is recurrent. When $w_i=i^{-a}$ for every $i$, this happens if and only if $a\leqslant1$.
> - If the series $\sum\limits_kw_k$ converges, then $P_1(T_0\,\text{infinite})\ne0$, that is, the Markov chain is transient. When $w_i=i^{-a}$ for every $i$, this happens if and only if $a\gt1$.

**Nota:** The probabilistic structure hidden behind these furious computations (particularly simple in the present case) is called an *electric network*, see the small book [Random walks and electric networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001057) by Doyle and Snell for a masterful exposition of the subject.